# MySQL Query: Multiple joins on the same field returning multiple categories - HOW?

Tags: mysql, join

We have a table with around 40000 id's in - some of these IDs are parents of other IDs (and subsequently some of those are parents of others in a different table). I'd like to use magic, persistance and some joins to work out which categories are related by querying against a field that contains all the child IDs (known as arrange).

So the way this works is Category table:

```
id       name               arrange
16       Alarms             c,119|c,117|c,4607|c,3366|c,709|c,4204|c,624|c,626|c,625|c,4203|c,4201|c,4202
119      Carbon Monoxide    i,21434|i,272|i,274|i,28451
```

Products table then has the i, items from arrange in

```
id       name
272      Aico EI205ENA
274      AICO EI225EN
```

Basically I am running a query against a third orders table, and would like to create a table using joins which would be as such:

```
order date    id    name       id    name               id    name             quantity    price
13-06-2013    16    Alarms     119   Carbon Monoxide    272   Aico EI205ENA    2           10.00
```

At the moment I have:

```
 select * from cart c
 join prods p on p.id = c.item
 where order_status = ''
 and date_ordered != '0000-00-00'
 order by date_added desc;
```

Simple join where I now want to add the categories from the first example, how on earth do I query an array to get what I want?

(If it helps we have 3 tables I am interested in cart, product and category).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Noooooooo!!!!! See normalization!!

Comment: When I saw how your `arrange` column stores data.. I cried. For you. Because you shot your own foot with that :(

Comment: 1st Break your **Category** table, to simplify `arrange` column. Use Normalization for this.

Comment: While it is possible to do such a join (using some ugly tricks with FIND_IN_SET, or by manually splitting the array within SQL) it is FAR better to normalise the database. Split the arrange field off into a different table, with each name having multiple rows, one for each value from your 'array'. This can then easily be joined. If you really do want to keep things as they are then given the table definitions I could possibly knock up a query, but at the moment I can see how with your example data id 272 relates to both Alarms and Carbon Monoxide

Answer (score 0):

I have now realised how the tables join together.

What you want to do is possible with something like the following. It will be slow and the main reason I am putting it here is to show how nasty and unreadable it is, as an encouragement to normalise the database.

```
SELECT * 
FROM cart c
INNER JOIN prods p 
ON p.id = c.item
INNER JOIN Category z1
ON FIND_IN_SET(CONCAT('i-', p.id), REPLACE(REPLACE(z1.arrange, 'i,', 'i-'), '|', ',')) > 0
INNER JOIN Category z2
ON FIND_IN_SET(CONCAT('c-', z1.id), REPLACE(REPLACE(z2.arrange, 'c,', 'c-'), '|', ',')) > 0
WHERE order_status = ''
AND date_ordered != '0000-00-00'
ORDER BY date_added DESC
```

FIND_IN_SET is a function that looks for a value in a comma separated list. This is taking your delimited list, changing all the occurrences of **i,** and changing them to **i-** then changing all the occurrences of **|** and changing them to commas. Then it looks for i- concatenated with the id in the resulting comma separated list. Then does the same joining against category again to get the match for the parent category.

Comment: Kickstart - you are right, it is incredibly slow - but only because of our horrible database layout. I will do some investigation into the normalisation of it, sadly I don't think we'll have the resource to worry about it for now.

Really appreciate your help though, played around with FIND_IN_SET for the first time today and got somewhere but not far.

Thanks again!